# Do I use a crosstab() or case when function to achieve results needed [postgresql]

Tags: sql, postgresql, case, crosstab

I have a table that has the following data:

```
type     | id  | name  | imps | clicks |  mo  | conv |
---------+---- +-------|------|--------|------|------|
custom   | 1   |  new1 |  5   |   5    |  8   |      |
default  | 2   |  new2 |  34  |        |  8   |   5  |
other    | 3   |  old3 |  34  |   3    |  8   |      |
other    | 4   |  old4 |  63  |   2    |  9   |   3  |
other    | 3   |  old3 |  23  |   9    |  9   |      |
other    | 3   |  old3 |  12  |   1    |  10  |   1  |
```

I want to perform the crosstab() **OR** the case function but I just can't figure out how to use it. I've looked at other questions on here regarding the same thing but I can't quite grasp it.

I want the results to look like this:

```
type     | id  | name  | oldimps | oldclicks |  oldconv  | newimps | newclicks | newconv |
---------+---- +-------|---------|-----------|-----------|---------|-----------|---------|
custom   | 1   |  new1 |    5    |     5     |           |         |           |         |
default  | 2   |  new2 |    34   |           |     5     |         |           |         |
other    | 3   |  old3 |    57   |     12    |           |   12    |     1     |    1    |
other    | 4   |  old4 |    63   |     2     |     1     |         |           |         |
```

Basically, pivoting on the `mo` field is my goal. I want each `type` to have its own row and for the **highest** number `mo` to be accumulated to `newimps`|`newclicks`|`newconv` and for all other numbers of `mo` to be accumulated to `oldimps`|`oldclicks`|`oldconv`

What type of query/function would I go about using to perform the results I need?

Comment: how did you get newclicks = 1 for name = old3 from given data?

Comment: @RomanPekar Oops, I left out another row for first example. I've edited it to match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with cte as (
  select *, max(mo) over() as max_mo
  from Table1
)
select
    type, id, name,
    sum(case when mo <> max_mo then imps else 0 end) as oldimps,
    sum(case when mo <> max_mo then clicks else 0 end) as oldclicks,
    sum(case when mo <> max_mo then conv else 0 end) as oldconv,
    sum(case when mo = max_mo then imps else 0 end) as newimps,
    sum(case when mo = max_mo then clicks else 0 end) as newclicks,
    sum(case when mo = max_mo then conv else 0 end) as newconv
from cte
group by type, id, name
order by id;
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/9ceda/13)</kbd>**